# angular js model update not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model which gets updated with the result from an ajax request.

```
myController = function($scope){
  makeAjaxRequest(function(result){
   $scope.ResultsView = result.data;
  });

}
```

It seems like the view doesn't get updated automatically

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
 <span ng-model="ResultView.cost"></span>
</div>
```

The cost field is not getting updated.

**Update:**
Do I have to update each field individually like `cost` etc? Does angularjs have simple way to do it?

Comment: post code in jsfiddle

Comment: how do you call `makeAjaxRequest` with angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `scope`'s [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) method:

```
makeAjaxRequest(function(result){
   $scope.$apply(function () {
       $scope.ResultsView = result.data;
   });   
});
```

Comment: Can you give the link to the documentation also? I still am not able to make it work

Comment: Made a typo. Sorry, It worked. Can you still post the link to the doc?

Comment: @Tushar does my solution helped you? if yes may be it deserves an acceptance? ;)